# Disable Material UI's <LinearProgress /> animation

Tags: progress-bar, transform, material-ui

I am using [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/api/linear-progress/)'s `<LinearProgress variant="determinate" />` component which by default transforms the `scaleX()` property of a `<div>` inside another `<div>` whenever the value changes to visualize the current progress. It does so with an easing effect to make everything look smooth which generally is quite nice, however for the purpose of my application (audio seekbar) I would like to disable this animation entirely whenever the value changes.

Is it possible?

- Demo: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/olyyrp0vv5)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this using [overrides](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/)

```
bar: {
  transition: 'none'
}
...

...
<LinearProgress variant="determinate" classes={{ bar: classes.bar}} />
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this working for MUI v5 by using `sx`:

```
<FastLinearProgress
 sx={{
   "& .MuiLinearProgress-bar": {
      transition: "none"
   }
 }}
 variant="determinate"
 value={progress} 
/>
```

Comment: Yep, I have MUI `5.13.6` and this worked great - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it (for MUI v4) with "ordinary" css in className:

**CSS:**

```
.progressNoTransition div {
    transition: none;
}
```

**Component:**

```
import classes from "./Progress.css";
...

<LinearProgress
    variant="determinate"
    value={progress}
    className={classes.progressNoTransition}
/>
```