# How to reset Material UI LinearProgress after completion?

Tags: material-ui, progress-bar

I have a LinearProgress bar that goes from 0 to 100 over the course of a few seconds, then jumps back to 0 and repeats.

`<LinearProgress variant="determinate" value={progress}/>`

The first load looks great with the animation.  After it hits 100, the jump back to 0 ends up only reaching about 30, due to the long transition toward 0.  If I [turn off animations altogether](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55593367/disable-material-uis-linearprogress-animation/55593844), the jump from 100 to 0 is clean, but the progress from 0 to 100 is choppy.

Is it possible to have the animation/transition on while increasing but not decreasing/reset without swapping components?  I see [it's answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60134518/react-bootstrap-how-to-animate-progressbar-when-value-is-increasing-but-not-wh) for React Bootstrap, not sure if I can apply a similar technique here.

This works okay-ish, but would really like to avoid swapping components if possible:

```
const NoTransitionLinearProgress = withStyles({
  bar: {
    transition: 'none'
  }
})(LinearProgress);

const ProgressBar = () => {
    const progress = useSelector(state => state.progress);
  
    if (progress > 0) {
      return (
        <LinearProgress variant="determinate" value={progress}/>
      );
    }
    return (
      <NoTransitionLinearProgress variant="determinate" value={progress}/>
    );
}
```

Comment: You should create a minimal reproducible example (could be on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/))

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a way to disable the animation of the reset from 100 to 0 on the `LinearProgress` as well and found a solution combining the two threads you linked:

By using `transition: none` (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55593844/13238253)) when the `aria-valuenow` attribute has the value `0` (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60164171/13238253)) the reset to 0 can be done without animation. This does **not** however work for decreasing values in general. It only works for the reset to 0.

#### [Sandbox with visualized example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-bassi-tdlyn)

## Progress Bar component

```typescript
    <LinearProgress
      className={classes.progressBar}
      variant="determinate"
      value={progress}
      classes={{ bar: classes.progressBarInner }}
    />
```

## CSS

```typescript
        progressBar: {
          // Disable the transition animation from 100 to 0 inside the progress bar
          '&[aria-valuenow="0"]': {
            "& > $progressBarInner": {
              transition: "none"
            }
          }
        },
        progressBarInner: {}
```